# getStringExtra() function of intent is returning null

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an edit text from where I am taking the text and sending it to MainActivity using `putExtra()`
but when the `getStringExtra()` is returning null.

SecondActivity:-

```
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            if(editWordView.text.isNotEmpty()){
                val word = editWordView.text.toString()
                intent.putExtra("Word", word)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

In first log it is showing null and last line is not executing as the word is null

MainActivity:-

```
        val intent = Intent()
        val word = intent.getStringExtra("Word")
        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity: $word")
        word?.let {
            viewModel.insert(Word(word))
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Inserted $word")
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent()
```

You are creating a new, empty `Intent`. That will not contain any extras. Instead, you need to get the `Intent` from the activity:

- via `getIntent()` for the `Intent` used to create the activity
- in `onNewIntent()` for any `Intent` used to bring an already-running instance of this activity back to the foreground

Answer (score 1):

To get value in the Second activity you can also try this, it works perfect for me!

```
val word = intent.extras?.getString("Word")
```